# How do I nullify an element in an array of integers in golang

Tags: arrays, go

I have the following array: `[45,23,89,23]`.
I want to nullify **in-place** the last element.
Result should be `[45,23,89,_]`.
I can't do the following

```
myArr := [4]int{45,23,89,23}
myArr[3]=nil
```

This question is abstraction of the real problem, I can not change the type of the array, and I must do this in-place.

Another way to look at this, How do I make this 4 elements array be like this:

```
myArr := [4]int{45,23,89}
```

Comment: `myArr := [4]int{45,23,89}` creates an array that contains `[45, 23, 89, 0]`. So that'd be `myArr[3]=0`. You can't make a `[4]int` not have four elements, and the zero value of `int` is... zero.

Comment: What is wrong with this question?

Answer (score 0):

Golang does not allow the exact behaviour you are looking for. So, the only solution is a workaround. There are several approaches you can take, but they will depend on your constraints.

#### Set your own null value outside the boundaries you are working on.

If your values are in the range `[A, B]` where `B < math.MaxInt (or A > math.MinInt)` you could define your own null as `math.MaxInt (or math.MinInt)`.

Like:

```
import math

const MyNil = math.MAXINT

...

arr[3] = MyNil

...

if arr[x] != MyNil {
   // Do some work with arr[x]
}
```

---

#### Have an array helper

You could have another slice of the same size to track whether an element is nil or not.

Like:

```
isNil := make([]bool, len(arr))

...

isNil[3] = true

...

if !isNil[x] {
    // Do some work with arr[x]
}
```

---

> Take into account that if you need to pass this array to another part of the code, you will have to create a convention. Especially if you are working with other devs. But if that's the case probably will be better just to change the type to a more suitable one.